# copy works in gradle but zip gives weird error

Tags: gradle

I am trying to use the zip in gradle and my build worked fine until I added this to my section for the "webserver" project (maybe my question should be why does the copy work without task in front of it?????...I am just really confused by the difference between copy and zip if you need task in front of zip but not copy below)

```
assemble << {
    zip {
       from '.'
       includes ['app/*','conf/*','public/*','play-1.2.4/*','run*.sh']
    }
}
```

The error is

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':webserver:assemble'.

> Could not find method zip() for arguments [build_3nljqgmljp29v06751h102sq8b$_run_closure3_closure16_closure18@7cc8e407] on task ':webserver:assemble'.
>   
>   I don't understand as I am using copy successfully like so

```
copy { from fixedLibDir into genLibDir }
```

Also, I am getting really really confused by the documentation as in the documentation, they almost always have

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {

}
```

I just want to call a zip task not create a new one every time, so the documentation examples seem to be very bad...they should be examples of using zip task not creating a new one(after all, who wants to create a new zip task when one already exists??)  **OR am I missing something here?**  At any rate, that confused me when getting started with gradle alot and I am guessing it will confuse others.  It might be nice to show both using it and defining a new one(though I still don't get why I would define a new one).

MORE INFO/UPDATE:
I also tried this code which runs and I see the print out message but I see no zip file in my webserver/output/libs directory as I would expect???

```
assemble << {
    println "I'm zipping up now"
    task zip(type: Zip) {
        from('.') {
            fileMode = 0755
            include 'run*.sh'
            include 'app/*'
        }
    }

}
```

later,
Dean

Comment: The last snippet is a task declaration inside a task action; that's never going to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `copy` works, is because it's a global utility function defined in `Project` (see [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3acopy%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)). So you can call `copy` from anywhere, and it will work.

On the other hand there is no equivalent `zip` method. Perhaps, because zipping usually need more configuration than copying, like specifying zip archive name, or maybe they just missed it out. This means that you have to use the `task zip(type: Zip){ from ... into ... }`  syntax for zip.

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to `Copy`, `copy` is *not* a task; it is just a method on the `Project` class. Gradle doesn't have any information about, and doesn't control the execution of, methods like it does for tasks. Therefore, methods have some drawbacks over the corresponding tasks (e.g. no up-to-date check) and should only be used when a task is not an option (which is less often than you think).

As for `zip`, there is simply no such method, in particular not on the `Project` class. The best place to look up such information is the [Gradle DSL reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

> > after all, who wants to create a new zip task when one already exists

Not sure what you mean by that; maybe you are confusing *tasks* and *task types*. It's perfectly normal to use a separate task for every zip file to be created.

PS: I recommend to take a step back and learn more about Gradle before tackling real-world builds.

Comment: when I dive in, I dive pretty deep(I have read the docs twice and just solidifying/understanding now).  This clears up a lot of my confusion.  thanks,

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct way to do this now is

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
    from('.') {
        include 'run*.sh'
        include 'app/*'
    }
}

assemble.dependsOn('myZip')
    //This last line is important of course!!!!
```

I am not sure what the following does to be honest now as it doesn't do anything except println

```
assemble << {
    println "I'm zipping up now"
    task zip(type: Zip) {
        from('.') {
            fileMode = 0755
            include 'run*.sh'
            include 'app/*'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's very important to understand that a Gradle build progresses in three phases: _initialization_, _configuration_, and _execution_. The latter snippet tries to add a task in the _execution_ phase of the build.  That's too late - adding a task is a form of configuration and therefore has to be done in the configuration phase. At the end of the configuration phase, Gradle creates an execution plan that determines which tasks to execute and in what order.

Comment: thanks for all your help, I think I have figured out all the corners now(and yup, I had read about the 3 phases).  I think it's starting to sink in(I would have wanted a method there, but that has downsides)...now to go evangalize gradle to others ;).  I like it, just took a while to understand alot of it.